# Create-React-App: What's the best way to include CSS from node_module directory

Tags: create-react-app

I'm trying to include some CSS in my create-react-app project. The CSS is from a 3rd party NPM package and therefore its in the node_modules directory.

I tried:
`import '/node_modules/packagename/css/styles.css';`

But I get the error:

> Module not found: You attempted to import /node_modules/packagename/css/styles.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

I would prefer to not move the CSS to src/ so it can be updated via NPM. I could symlink but as I develop on windows and deploy to linux this isn't ideal.

What's the best way from me to include the CSS?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Find the path of the css file

example: `./node_modules/packagename/dist/css/styles.css`

Import using the path related to node_modules (anything after `node_modules/` )

```
import 'packagename/dist/css/styles.css'
```

Comment: you should definitely not be using relative paths to anything in the `node_modules` folder. node_modules css in create-react-app can be imported the same way as any js package in the node modules folder

Comment: Correct! If the css loader is defined properly, it should load the css from the package without the relative path.

Comment: @AfzalHossain Perhaps you should update your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 51):

relative paths are unnecessary from node_modules and should not be the recommended way to include the css

all you have to do is leave off the preceding slash and node_modules directory same as importing a js package from node modules:

`import 'package/css/style-to-import.css'`

when using (s)css imports, use the tilde (`~`) to indicate an absolute import:

`@import '~package/css/style-to-import.css'`

Comment: Yes, mostly the css will be in `<package>/dist` folder

Answer (score 11):

A distinction not made from the previous answers is it depends on where you're importing the CSS into; a component or into a stylesheet.

If you're importing a `node_modules` stylesheet into a component, you don't need a relative path like mentioned above.

```
import 'packagename/dist/css/styles.css'
```

However, if you're importing a `node_modules` stylesheet into a CSS/SCSS file, you need to use tilde `~`.

```
@import '~packagename/dist/css/styles.css'
```

Answer (score -7):

I found this a bug of a pain. specially my webpack.config.js is not running anymore.

specially react app is now running in src folder and the import files need to be in the public folder.

i was using materialize-social and found out the easiest way is to move node_module file folder "materialize-social" to the public directory any other way please commend it down.