# create react app and SVG from node modules folder

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

So, I am creating a simple playing cards game using create-react-app and the [cardsJS](https://github.com/richardschneider/cardsJS)

The thing is, I can't figure out how to include the styles and svg files from the `node_modules` folder, what's is the reactive way, the best practice in such case?

I want to be able to get a specific card from that folder dynamically, bearing in mind that the cards folder contains 52 svg files representing the cards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658500/create-react-app-whats-the-best-way-to-include-css-from-node-module-directory

Comment: @froston thanks for your reply, but in my case, I have a folder that contains svg files representing playing cards, it's a folder full of those, I am having troubles displaying them to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can import SVG files and use them in React.

For example:

```
import srcCard2C from 'cardsJS/cards/2C.svg'

render() {
  return <img class='card' src={srcCard2C} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is a better one :D but, how can I get the card Dynamically? Say I want to get the Ace of Spade, which is named `AS.svg` from that folder, How can I achive that?

Comment: the cards folders contains all the cards, and i want to be able to get any one of them dynamically. bearing in mind that the folder contains 52 cards

Comment: You could import all the cards in one and then dynamically load them. `import * as cards` from 'cardsJS/cards' kind of this.